# Find row with same value from two ids

Tags: mysql

I'am looking for a query to get the conversation id from two participant_id paramters of my function:

Php function to get the conversation_id

```
public function findByUsers($user1,$user2)
```

Mysql table participant_conversation

```
+--------------+-------------------------+
|participant_id| participant_conversation|
+--------------+-------------------------+
|42360         |1                        |
+--------------+-------------------------+
|42362         |5                        |
+--------------+-------------------------+
|42363         |1                        |
+--------------+-------------------------+
```

Thanks for help

Edit : I found the solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT ( participant_conversation ) 
FROM users_conversations_participants 
WHERE participant_id IN ( 42360, 42361 ) 
GROUP BY participant_id 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Thanks for help !

I found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's to the question:

```
$sql = "SELECT participant_id, participant_conversation FROM participant_conversation WHERE participant_id IN ($user1, $user2)";
```

Then can simply use a while loop to get their respective participant_converation.